# I don't understand tests in Django, Can you help me please?

Tags: python, django

I am having a hard time with tests in Django and Python, for my final project I am making a  forums website, but I don't really have any idea how or what my tests should be. Here is the views page from mysite file. Could someone please walk me through what I should test for besides if a user is logged in.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from settings import MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render_to_response
from django.template import loader, Context, RequestContext
from mysite2.forum.models import *

def list_forums(request):
     """Main listing."""
     forums = Forum.objects.all()
     return render_to_response("forum/list_forums.html", {"forums":forums},      context_instance=RequestContext(request))



def mk_paginator(request, items, num_items):
    """Create and return a paginator."""
    paginator = Paginator(items, num_items)
    try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
    except ValueError: page = 1

    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
        items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return items


def list_threads(request, forum_slug):
    """Listing of threads in a forum."""
    threads = Thread.objects.filter(forum__slug=forum_slug).order_by("-created")
    threads = mk_paginator(request, threads, 20)
     template_data = {'threads': threads} 
    return render_to_response("forum/list_threads.html", template_data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def list_posts(request, forum_slug, thread_slug):
    """Listing of posts in a thread."""
    posts = Post.objects.filter(thread__slug=thread_slug,  thread__forum__slug=forum_slug).order_by("created")
    posts = mk_paginator(request, posts, 15)
    thread = Thread.objects.get(slug=thread_slug)
    template_data = {'posts': posts, 'thread' : thread}
    return render_to_response("forum/list_posts.html", template_data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def post(request, ptype, pk):
    """Display a post form."""
    action = reverse("mysite2.forum.views.%s" % ptype, args=[pk])
    if ptype == "new_thread":
        title = "Start New Topic"
        subject = ''
    elif ptype == "reply":
        title = "Reply"
        subject = "Re: " + Thread.objects.get(pk=pk).title
    template_data = {'action': action, 'title' : title, 'subject' : subject}

    return render_to_response("forum/post.html", template_data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def new_thread(request, pk): 
    """Start a new thread."""
    p = request.POST
    if p["subject"] and p["body"]:
        forum = Forum.objects.get(pk=pk)
        thread = Thread.objects.create(forum=forum, title=p["subject"], creator=request.user)
        Post.objects.create(thread=thread, title=p["subject"], body=p["body"], creator=request.user)
     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dbe.forum.views.forum", args=[pk]))

def reply(request, pk):
    """Reply to a thread."""
     p = request.POST
    if p["body"]:
        thread = Thread.objects.get(pk=pk)
        post = Post.objects.create(thread=thread, title=p["subject"],         body=p["body"],
        creator=request.user)
     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dbe.forum.views.thread", args=[pk]) +      "?page=last")
```

Comment: You can go through and test to make sure every template loads. Use the django testclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could test:

- If you have the right number of pages for the objects you're paginating.
- If the page you're viewing contains the right object range. If trying to access a page that doesn't exist returns the
  appropriate error.
- If your views for listing objects and object detail return the correct HTTP status code (200)

For starters. Hope that helps you out.

Comment: You're welcome. A good rule of thumb is that you need a test for just about anything you're writing yourself, whether it be a method or property on a model, to a view function that's expected to have a certain outcome, etc. You might have a look at Karen Tracey's excellent book on Django Testing and Debugging: http://www.amazon.com/Django-Testing-Debugging-Karen-Tracey/dp/1847197566/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1323227880&sr=8-1

Answer (score 3):

First read the [Django testing documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/). You might also want to read [this book](http://www.packtpub.com/django-1-1-testing-and-debugging/book). It's dated in some areas, but testing is still pretty much the same now as it was in 1.1.

It's a bit much of a topic to cover in an SO answer.

Comment: I have read them and I have a book but I don't understand much besides login validation, Should I even bother with any other validation

Comment: Validation and testing aren't the same thing. Validation is where you check user input for sanity. Testing is where you feed known inputs to your code and check that the outputs match expected values, for starters. Which are you talking about?